# Phone Number Validation Should Fail For All Same Number

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regex where it should fail if all same numbers supplied as phone number. When I supplied with with below input it passes the validation. 
`999.999.9999` or `999-999-9999` or `999 999 9999`. Any suggestion on regex pattern on how to fail validation it supplied all same number.

```
    private static boolean validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNo) {
        //validate phone numbers of format "1234567890"
        if (phoneNo.matches("\\d{10}")) return true;

        //validating phone number with -, . or spaces
        else if(phoneNo.matches("\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{4}")) return true;

        //Invalid phone number where 999.999.9999 or 999-999-9999 or 999 999 9999
        else if(phoneNo.matches"(\\D?[0-9]{3}\\D?)[\\s][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}")) return false;

        //return false if nothing matches the input
        else return false;

    }
```

Comment: Are you asking for a string that will make this method return false? `a` will do

Comment: yes, it should return false if same number is given as input like 111.111.1111

Comment: While this does not answer your question: Have you thought about alternative approaches that might not be based on a regexp. Any maintainers, incl. your future self might be thankful. In this case: If you extract all the numbers, and put them into a set and this set has a size of one, someone has entered the same number for all digits.

Comment: @reto you don't even need to use a set: you can simply check if the second, third etc  digits equal the first digit.

Comment: @AndyTurner you are definitely right, there are various ways to do this.

Comment: Something like `(\d)(?:[\s.-]|\1)+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a single regex:

`(?!(\d)\1{2}\D?\1{3}\D?\1{4})\d{3}([-. ]?)\d{3}\2\d{4}`

As Java code, your method would be:

```
private static boolean validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNo) {
    // Check if phone number is valid format (optional -, . or space)
    // e.g. "1234567890", "123-456-7890", "123.456.7890", or "123 456 7890"
    // and is that all digits are not the same, e.g. "999-999-9999"
    return phoneNo.matches("(?!(\\d)\\1{2}\\D?\\1{3}\\D?\\1{4})\\d{3}([-. ]?)\\d{3}\\2\\d{4}");
}
```

*Explanation*

The regex is in 2 parts:

`(?!xxx)yyy`

The `yyy` part is:

`\d{3}([-. ]?)\d{3}\2\d{4}`

Which means:

```
\d{3}     Match 3 digits
([-. ]?)  Match a dash, dot, space, or nothing, and capture it (capture group #2)
\d{3}     Match 3 digits
\2        Match the previously captured separator
\d{4}     Match 4 digits
```

This means that it will match e.g. `123-456-7890` or `123.456.7890`, but not `123.456-7890`

The [`(?!xxx)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) part is a zero-width negative lookahead, i.e. it matches if the `xxx` expression doesn't match, and the `xxx` part is:

`(\d)\1{2}\D?\1{3}\D?\1{4}`

Which means:

```
(\d)   Match a digit and capture it (capture group #1)
\1{2}  Match 2 more of the captured digit
\D?    Optionally match a non-digit
\1{3}  Match 3 more of the captured digit
\D?    Optionally match a non-digit
\1{4}  Match 4 more of the captured digit
```

Since the second part has already verified the separators, the negative look-ahead is just using a more relaxed `\D` to skip any separator character.

Answer (score 3):

Although you can write a regex to do this it feels more readable with iteration.

```
boolean uniqueDigits = phoneNo.chars()
        .filter(Character::isDigit)
        .distinct()
        .count() >= 2;
```

Comment: Note that if the number format itself has been validated you could also use `filter(Character::isDigit)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regexs to match telephone numbers whose digits are not all the same :

- for the 0123456789 format :

  ```
  (?!(.)\\1{9})\\d{10}
  ```

  You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/IzD0fF/1).
- for the 012-345-6789 format :

  ```
  (?!(.)\\1{2}[-.\\s]\\1{3}[-.\\s]\\1{4})\\d{3}[-.\\s]\\d{3}[-.\\s]\\d{4}
  ```

  You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/qtkRSK/1).

It relies on negative lookahead to check that the numbers we're going to match aren't all the same digit.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use Stream API instead of complex regex

```
if(phoneNo.chars().filter(c -> c != '.' && c != '-' && c != ' ').distinct().count() > 1)
```

or

```
phoneNo.chars().filter(c -> ".- ".indexOf(c) > -1).distinct().count() > 1
```

or

```
phoneNo.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).distinct().count() > 1
```